# Make TextWrangler recognize drupal files as PHP?

Tags: php, drupal, textwrangler

I am writing some drupal modules and such and I would like textwrangler to do syntax highlighting for me. The files are PHP files, but they need different extensions to work with drupal (i.e. `.module`). I've added ".module" -> PHP in the Custom Extension Mappings, but it's not doing any syntax highlighting like it does with my .php files. I've restarted TextWrangler, but it's not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying it myself as well, but this is all I could find from them, too.

If you find that a file name extension isn't being mapped to your desired language, just add it in the "Custom Extension Mappings" list. Custom mappings will always take precedence over built-in mappings if there's a conflict.

From Bare Bones -- http://www.barebones.com/support/textwrangler/current_notes.html

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  I ended going to the lower left hand corner of the window and select PHP from the drop-down for that particular file.  That approach worked fine for me.

I think TextWrangler remember old syntax highlighting so if you opened the file before you changed the extension that it why it isn't changing now.  Just a guess (not a fact).